# How to measure quality and quantity of DNA?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, lab-techniques

I would like to mesure DNA. I quantify the concentration with Qubit fluorometer, but I would like to know also quality of DNA. I try BioAnalyzer (Agilent),but without success. Bioanalyzer measure DNA samples from 100 to 7 000 bp (12 000 bp). Problem is that my DNA is not sheared, I would like to quantify whole mouse DNA. Have you any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run your DNA sample on agarose gel to see, whether you have significant degradation.

If you are interested in contamination, you can make a standard photometric analysis to assess the [260/280 and 260/230 ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleic_acid_quantitation#Spectrophotometric_analysis) and absorbance at 320 nm on NanoDrop or even something similar to Eppendorf's BioPhotometer.

In case RNA may be an obstacle for some down-stream procedures, with Qubit you can also measure separately DNA and RNA concentrations and then decide if you have too much RNA and it's worth treating your sample with RNase.

Comment: I run DNA on gel...but I need some number for comparison...NanoDrop is probably the best option in my case :) Thanks!